# LateError (LateInitializationError: Field '_state@504051772' has already been initialized.)in flutter_map package

Tags: flutter

hello actually I am trying to load FlutterMap after successful Authentication and I am using providers to redirect to map screen after getting token but I am not Abel to redirect to map screen after Authentication here I am facing above error below is my main.dart

```
home: value.isAuth ? const mapscreen() : Otp(),
          routes: {
            'verifyotp': (context) {
              
              return value.isAuth ? const mapscreen() : const VerifyOtp();
            },
            'mapview': (context) => const mapscreen(),
          },
```

in the above code when I remove value.isAuth ? const mapscreen() from home: then it is working and I am Abel to display after validating otp but when I add value.isAuth ? const mapscreen() this code before Otp() in  home: then it is throwing error kindly help me to solve this problem

following is my map screen

```
class _mapscreen extends State<mapscreen> {
  TextEditingController location = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var userdata = Provider.of<UserBookings>(context);

    return Scaffold(
      body: FlutterMap(
        options: MapOptions(
            onTap: (p, l) async {
              setState(() {
                userdata.currentlocation = l;
              });
            },
            center: userdata.currentlocation,
            zoom: 15.0,
            maxZoom: 17),
        mapController: userdata.mapController,
        layers: [
          TileLayerOptions(
            urlTemplate:
                "https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/santosh8712/cl2xkbjd8000q14nxzevw3dkf/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x?access_token=pk.eyJ1Ijoic2FudG9zaD",
            
          ),
          MarkerLayerOptions(
            rotate: true,
            markers: [
              Marker(
                width: 100.0,
                height: 100.0,
                rotate: true,
                point: userdata.currentlocation ?? LatLng(15, -15),
                builder: (ctx) => const Icon(
                  Icons.person_pin_circle_rounded,
                  color: Colors.red,
                  size: 45,
                ),
              ),
            ],
```

and I am sure that error is coming from map controller

Comment: can you send mapscreen page codes

Comment: @Yunus Emre Çelik i had updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a MapController, it must initialised and then passed to the FlutterMap. This attaches them until the widget is destroyed/disposed.

```
final mapController = MapController();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) =>
    FlutterMap(
        mapController: mapController,
        ...
    );
```

Comment: Hi there. As a maintainer of flutter_map, please note that this is not 'the right way', but a possible way. Since v2.1.0, this method of initialisation has become essentially useless. Please see the documentation for more info.

Comment: ok then can you please say alt solution for this problem

Comment: You should read the updated flutter_map documentation, as it includes a working example. A recent update reworked the controller lifecycle, so it's much less error prone now. There's no huge reason to move away from this method, I just wouldn't recommend adding it to a new project.

Comment: ok tq I will check and update the answer